# HTTP metrics using the Servlet filter through Micrometer

Tags: micrometer

Is there a way to collect HTTP metrics using the Servlet filter (i.e. non Spring application) through Micrometer. I am looking for a solution similar to io.micrometer.jersey2.server.MetricsApplicationEventListener where its in the case of Jersey.... But I am looking something at the HTTP level instead of depending on REST....

Answer (score 4):

If your choice of Servlet Container happens to be Tomcat, you can use [`TomcatMetrics`](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/master/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/binder/tomcat/TomcatMetrics.java). It will register a bunch of Tomcat-related metrics for you, e.g.: `tomcat.servlet.request` and `tomcat.servlet.error`. You can see how is it auto-configured by spring-boot-actuator in [`TomcatMetricsAutoConfiguration`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/metrics/web/tomcat/TomcatMetricsAutoConfiguration.java) and [`TomcatMetricsBinder`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/metrics/web/tomcat/TomcatMetricsBinder.java), based on these you can use it in a non-spring app as well.

If you need something more advanced/granular, you can create a servlet `Filter` (I don't think micrometer has any) where you can measure what you need using a `Timer`. You can check what spring-boot-actuator does and based on that, you can implement your own `Filter`, see: [`WebMvcMetricsAutoConfiguration`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/metrics/web/servlet/WebMvcMetricsAutoConfiguration.java) and [`WebMvcMetricsFilter`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/metrics/web/servlet/WebMvcMetricsFilter.java).